# Linux c++ recvfrom() changes (destroys) the [socket] file descriptor

Tags: c++, linux, sockets, stack-overflow, berkeley-sockets

I have written a simple UDP server. Well, naturally I use `recvfrom()` function somewhere in it. I have searched the net for it, and found that it is caused by the buffer overflow. Is this true? But I can't figure why my code fails and throws the same error, here is the part associated with `recvfrom()`:

```
char messageFromClient[1024] = {0};
returnStatus = recvfrom(udpSocket, &messageFromClient, strlen(messageFromClient), 0, (struct sockaddr*)&udpSocket,
                                &addrlen);
```

The file descriptor before invocation of `recvfrom()` is `3` but when I call it, it changes to `-187301886`

Comment: Are you sure about `strlen(messageFromClient)`? Shouldn't that be `sizeof(messageFromClient)`

Comment: I have used sizeof(), but to no avail

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code fails because you specify 0 receive buffer size and you pass the socket file descriptor as the peer address argument (which overwrites its value):

Fix:

```
char messageFromClient[1024];
sockaddr_in addr;
socklen_t addrlen = sizeof addr;
ssize_t received = recvfrom(udpSocket, messageFromClient, sizeof messageFromClient, 0, (sockaddr*)&addr, &addrlen);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I did get the point and found what a mistake I'd made

Comment: @MostafaTalebi Very well then.